# EF and Sqlite adding records with the same key with on conflict ignore throw exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

In db creation I specify key constraints to ignore on conflict, but when I add 2 or more elements with the same keys, EF throws   DBconcurrency exception when it is supposed to add the first record and ignore the rest of the conflicts. How can I implement or enforce that?

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: `DBconcurrency exception when is supose to add the firts record and ignore the rest of the conflicts.` What makes you think it is supposed to add the first and ignore the rest of the conflicts?

Comment: I'm using EF6 and SQlite with ADO.NET Database first. I know AddorUpdate exist but I don't want to overwrite what is already in the database, just ignore. Sorry for not including this on the original question.

Comment: Well I'm reading the docs and On Conflict clause specifying "Ignore" is suppose to do that, ignoring the conflict and continuing with the rest of the changes.

Comment: I look forward to seeing your [mcve].

Comment: I just want to know how to do it, when I'm designing the databse, in the table key constraints definition I specify Ignore in the OnConflict clause, as I read here [link](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) and I was specking that EF will do that, add a bulk of records and ignore if one or more of them already exist in the database rather than throw me and exception and not adding any records, that's the issue I'm having, I want to add has many records I can and ignore the conflicts.

Comment: You can't apply Sqlite syntax to EF. EF either commits or rolls back one entire transaction (i.e one `SaveChanges` call). Therefore, MCVE required.

Comment: EF cannot determine wether the incorrect number of updated rows is due to concurrency or due to a db trigger (those are not directly supported in EF). EF is used to communicate with a DB, not mirror its behavior.